# Having difficulty using Z-Index in WPF

Tags: wpf, z-index, layer

I've followed some examples trying to layer a rectangle over the WebBrowser object:

[Here is the MSDN example link.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2006/06/13/controlling-zorder-using-the-zindex-property.aspx) (I got it to work)

[Layers issue using Z-Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195467/layers-issue-using-z-index)

Here is the code I'm trying to get to work:

```
<Grid>
    <Canvas Margin="2,4,0,-450" >
        <Rectangle Height="452" Canvas.ZIndex="1000" Name="rectangle1" Stroke="Black" Width="524" Opacity=".5" Fill="#8CBABABA" Canvas.Top="-7" Canvas.Left="-3" />
        <WebBrowser Name="mapBrowser" Canvas.ZIndex="999" Margin="5,5,5,5"  Height="452" Width="516" Canvas.Top="-11" />
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

I'm trying to make the `WebBrowser` appear ***grayed out*** by making the rectangle appear over top of it.  I'll also disable it.

**Can anybody point to what I'm doing wrong?**

Comment: Which version of .Net? [There are known "airspace" issues with WPF and WebBrowser.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935964/what-is-a-good-alternative-to-the-wpf-webbrowser-control)

Comment: *embarrassed* @sixlettervariables How do I check.  I'm VS2010 if that tells you.

Comment: You're using at most 4.0, so yeah you won't be able to overlay anything with the `WebBrowser` control.

Comment: Pooh.  Any simple workarounds?

Comment: the WPF webbrowser is actually a wrapper around the ActiveX stuff. you wont be able to place WPF UI elements over it. I suggest taking a look at Awesomium.

Comment: Would it be possible to place an entirely new WPF page on top of that WebBrowser?  I'm running into things I can use that are not easily positioned, or things that will display something useful but will not appear on top of the WebBrowser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by creating a .png image which I placed in the same space as the webbrowser.  It looks like a grayed-out version of what first appears in the webbrowser.  Then I conditionally hid the webbrowser which makes the image visible.  This is the only way I've found to make it work using .Net 4.0.